# unable to read connection.json while creating a business network card for hyperledger fabric

Tags: hyperledger-composer

I am currently working on this project:

https://github.com/html5-ninja/hyperledger-vote-app

I installed per-requisites and development environment as mentioned in read me.

I am unable to do "Creating a business network card for the Hyperledger Fabric administrator" in the 3 rd step(Deploying to Hyperledger Fabric for a single organization)
It is showing this error:
Error: Unable to read file: /home/shahin/fabric-tools/connection.json
Command failed
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xQwNk.png)

Thanks for the help in advance

Comment: I have tried following way it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create connection.json file in the folder as shown in the [link](https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/tutorials/deploy-to-fabric-single-org) or you can copy it from fabric-sample's [basic-network](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples/tree/release-1.4/basic-network)

**Note**: you need to check x-type is available in connection file otherwise add (after name )

> "x-type": "hlfv1" ,